# Why is the promise still pending?

Tags: javascript, q

The following code returns:

```
output.isPending?: true
output.isRejected?: false
output.isFulfilled?: false
```

Why? I was expecting `output.isRejected` to be `true`.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/0.9.7/q.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/lib/jasmine.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script>
var output, bar;

bar = {
    doSomethingAsync: function() {
        var d = Q.defer();
        d.resolve('result');
        return d.promise;
    }
};

function Foo(bar) {
    this._bar = bar;

    this.go = function() {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        this._bar.doSomethingAsync()
            .then(onSuccess.bind(this, deferred));

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};

function onSuccess(deferred, result) {
    deferred.reject();
}

output = new Foo(bar).go()
    .finally(function() {
        console.log('output.isPending?:', output.isPending());
        console.log('output.isRejected?:', output.isRejected());
        console.log('output.isFulfilled?:', output.isFulfilled());
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `output` is not `new Foo(bar).go()`. It is assigned the result of the `.finally()` call, and will not be resolved untill the `finally` callback is done.

This will work as expected:

```
var output = new Foo(bar).go();
output.finally(function() {
    console.log('output.isPending?:', output.isPending());
    console.log('output.isRejected?:', output.isRejected());
    console.log('output.isFulfilled?:', output.isFulfilled());
});
```

Comment: From https://github.com/kriskowal/q - `If the handler returns a promise, outputPromise gets postponed.....`

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected a trivial delay function is unnecessary even for API's that are oblivious to promises. I can make sure the `resolve` or `reject` is always called, but after the promise itself is returned without delay. Here is an example:

```
var somePromise = function(path) {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    asyncFunction.request(path, function(result) {
        if (result.error === 0 && result.json !== null) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        } else {
            deferred.reject(result || {error: -1, message: "bad things happened"});
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

exports.someCall = function(req,res) {
    somePromise('path')
        .then(function (result) {
            ... do action ...
        }).catch(function (error) {
            ... handle error ...
        }); 
};
```

Comment: There's no need to `resolve` or `reject` only after returning a promise. All callbacks are called asynchronously anyway, regardless when/how you resolve your promise. Using deferreds like this even looks a bit like the [common antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Comment: This code still allows promises to be chained, eg:

    `exports.someCall = function(req,res) {
       somePromise('path')
           .then(function (result) {
               return somePromise('new path');
           }).then(function (result) {
              ... do something else ...`

Comment: Yes it does, but the `q.delay(1)` is still unnecessary?

Comment: As mentioned about [converting an API to promises](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/369446) I need to call some very slow HTTP calls which do not have their own wrapper for promises. The delay allows me to build a list of expensive HTTP calls and then use `q.allSettled` to wait for the results to come in.

Comment: An HTTP call might be slow, but it is not expensive. Just start all of them right now, and build a promise for each, without a delay, so that you can start waiting (`allSettled`) for them immediately. That delay does not do you any good except slowing you down 1 ms (or probably more) and increasing your memory usage.

Comment: I stand corrected, removing the `q.delay(1)` doesn't cause any problems. I have some bad habits left from the old C TCP API's.